# Unable to ssh with Git bash on Windows - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh, rsa, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

I am unable to ssh to a server on digitalocean. I have added the public key on the server where i want to reach. I am using Git for Windows. Using Windows 7. I have disabled StrictHostKeyChecking in the ssh_config file in GIT. The ssh-agent is running. Also added the key to agent with ssh-add command and it shows my private key correctly. My private key name is ct_devops and not id_rsa, is that the problem?
Please find below the output of the ssh -vT "hostname" command:

```
OpenSSH_7.7p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2p  14 Aug 2018
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to qa-baseversion.cxmweb.com [178.128.78.198] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/justinxa/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/justinxa/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/justinxa/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/justinxa/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/justinxa/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/justinxa/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/justinxa/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/justinxa/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/justinxa/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/justinxa/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to qa-baseversion.cxmweb.com:22 as 'JustinXa'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:OZBnpQ0IJBFGJH0tqPuNb9GnkjDPEZ1O2lvMs07imMo
debug1: Host 'qa-baseversion.cxmweb.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/justinxa/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:pVj+83I7wVJ7LF2mB5IVNDXbfXdyGYh7Cvh/9HRePGY JustinXa@CSSLLAPTOP-148
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/justinxa/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/justinxa/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/justinxa/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/justinxa/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/justinxa/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
JustinXa@qa-baseversion.cxmweb.com Permission denied (publickey).
```

Can someone please help in identifying what needs to be done or what i am doing wrong?
I checked other answers and tried all the possibilities, it still not working.

Comment: I came here with a similar question, however for you in think the `-i` flag will help. You can define what key ssh should use with that, e.g.:  `ssh -vT -i c:\Users\me\.ssh\ct_devops git@github.com`

Answer (score 0):

I have only tested this on Linux and OS X but the counterintuitive answer is this (will explain solution first, then why it works):

1. Use -i. I don't know the exact syntax variance for Windows, but on a *nix system I would do this:

   ssh -i /path/to/publickey root@dropletip
2. Copy the root ssh keys to the user you want to log in as:

   cp ~/.ssh/*.* /home/my user/.ssh get
3. Restart the ssh daemon (this depends on your Linux distro on the remote server)

In theory, this works because the root account has been set up with the right ssh key credentials (assuming you set them up right when you made the droplet). Your new user account hasn't.

Now, your question wasn't completely clear about what user you tried ssh-ing as. There has to be one and you need to do stuff as root at first, beyond just making a non-root user. There are a few other potential issues:

1. You may have too open permissions on your local keys. Some ideas for solving this on Windows are located at [this StackOverflow page](https://superuser.com/questions/1296024/windows-ssh-permissions-for-private-key-are-too-open), although I haven't personally tried to SSH to a droplet from Windows that had ssh key authentication.
2. It depends but I've noticed the "comment field" for SSH-keygen tends to populate the end of the public key with your username and local host name. I have sometimes noticed that if you create a public key and make sure you have one where the comment is set to root@yourDroplet and the other to yourNewUser@yourDroplet, this *may* go smoother; official docs say the comment field is ignored though.